How to get properties of ontology class owlready2
I try to make a frontend that automatically builds up based on the data properties of an ontology class. I asked ChatGpt for that and it came up with the following (excerpt):
from owlready2 import *
onto = get_ontology("my_ontology.owl").load()
ontology_class = onto[class_name]

and then - as a helper function of a Flask endpoint
def generate_form(ontology_class):
    form_html = f"<h1>Add {ontology_class.name}</h1><form id='ontologyForm'>"
    for prop in ontology_class.properties():
        if isinstance(prop, DataPropertyClass):
            form_html += f"<label for='{prop.name}'>{prop.name.capitalize()}:</label>"
            form_html += f"<input type='text' id='{prop.name}' name='{prop.name}' required><br>"
    form_html += "<button type='submit'>Add</button></form>"
    return form_html

Although the class I loaded has data properties, they are not shown. In the documentation of owlready2 I learned that the get_properties() method is only available on instances, but not on classes.
My question would be if there is a possibility to get the data properties of classes as well to automate a frontend generation from ontologies?
Thanks in advance for any hints or alternative solutions!!

Classes do not have data properties, they only have annotation properties. If there's an assertion with the class IRI as subject and the IRI of a data property as predicate, it's either an illegal punning on the property or a legal punning on the class name, in which case the properties are on an individual which shares the IRI with the class.
